# P/Invoke declarations should not be safe-critical

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke, code-analysis

My code imports following native methods:

- `DeleteObject`, `GetFontData` and `SelectObject` from gdi32.dll
- `GetDC` and `ReleaseDC` from user32.dll

I want to run the code in full and medium trust environments (I am fine with exceptions being thrown when these imported methods are indirectly used in medium trust environments).

When I run Code Analysis on the code I get warnings like:

> CA5122 P/Invoke declarations should not be safe-critical.
>
> P/Invoke method '`GdiFont.DeleteObject(IntPtr)`' is marked
>   safe-critical. Since P/Invokes may only be called by critical code,
>   this declaration should either be marked as security critical, or have
>   its annotation removed entirely to avoid being misleading.

Could someone explain me (in layman terms) what does this warning really mean?

I tried putting these imports in static `SafeNativeMethods` class as internal static methods but this doesn't make the warnings go away.

I didn't try to put them in `NativeMethods` because after reading [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2007/01/14/faq-how-do-i-fix-a-violation-of-movepinvokestonativemethodsclass.aspx) I am unsure that it's the right way to go because I don't want my code to be completely unusable in medium trust environments (I think this will be the consequence of moving imports to `NativeMethods`).

Honestly, I am pretty much confused about the real meaning of the warning and consequences of different options to suppressing it.

Could someone shed some light on all this?

EDIT:

My code target .NET 2.0 framework.

Assembly is marked with

```
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
```

Methods are declared like this:

```
[DllImport("gdi32")]
internal static extern int DeleteObject(HANDLE hObject);
```

Comment: What is your target framework? Does this apply http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/729254/bogus-ca5122-warning-about-p-invoke-declarations-should-not-be-safe-critical? What are the security attributes for the assembly?

Comment: @fsimonazzi please see update to my question. Unfortunately, I am not sure if the bug report applies in my case.

Comment: Why do you think it does not apply? Because it mentions 3.5? I think the argument that it shouldn't fire for 3.5 (but it does) also applies to 2.0.

Comment: @fsimonazzi I think you are right and the bug report also applies to my 2.0 assembly. I guess I should just suppress the warning then, right?

Comment: @fsimonazzi could you please summarize your comments into an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely an occurrence of this bug [Bogus CA5122 warning about P/Invoke declarations should not be safe-critical](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/729254/bogus-ca5122-warning-about-p-invoke-declarations-should-not-be-safe-critical), which manifests itself with pre-NET4 assemblies.

Comment: The bug report in the link seems to be gone.